# EclipseLink 2.7.0 and JPA API 2.2.0 - signature mismatch

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.2

When running a project built by maven with the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I get the following error at runtime:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.persistence.Cacheable"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

The javax.persistence-2.2.0 artifact is signed and contains the javax.persistence.Cacheable.class annotation, while the eclipselink-2.7.0 artifact is **not** signed and also contains the same java class annotation.

How can this be fixed?

**Edit**

Replacing the javax.persistence artifact version 2.2.0 by the version 2.1.1 fixes the problem (this one is not signed), but I'm not sure it's a normal situation.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm not separately listing the javax.persistence package in my pom.xml at all. It is inherited through eclipselink and maybe something else like javaee-api perhaps. With my build the error is this: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.persistence.Access"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package. I used this workaround: I downloaded a javax.persistence jar from some different provider altogether and then imported it into maven repository with the name org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence.

Comment: Thanks, replacing 2.2.1 for 2.1.1 indeed worked.

Answer (score 38):

Thanks Stéphane - the edit at the end of your question helped me "fix" the same problem. For anyone else who hits this as well - here is an expanded answer. This is what you need to "fix" things in your pom (until Eclipse fix things properly):

```
<!-- See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45870753 -->
<dependency>   
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This pulls in `eclipselink` but excludes the `javax.persistence` dependency that it tries to pull in and replaces it with an earlier version of `javax.persistence` that doesn't have the signing issue.

Aside: `javax.persistence` version `2.2.0` is explicitly pulled in, in the pom fragment shown in the original question, despite already being a transitive dependency of `eclipselink`.

### Explanation

Summary - the `eclipselink` artifact depends on `javax.persistence` and both contain classes that are in the package `javax.persistence`. However the `javax.persistence` jar is signed while the `eclipselink` one is not. So the Java runtime will complain, when loading a class from the package `javax.persistence` in the `eclipselink` jar, that it's lack of signing doesn't match with classes already loaded from the same package in the `javax.persistence` jar.

Details - if I put a breakpoint in `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(K, V)` with condition `"javax.persistence".equals(arg0)` then I see that `javax.persistence` is mapped to the following `CodeSource` value:

```
(file:/Users/georgehawkins/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.2.0/javax.persistence-2.2.0.jar [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN="Eclipse Foundation, Inc.", OU=IT, O="Eclipse Foundation, Inc.", L=Ottawa, ST=Ontario, C=CA
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
  ...
```

I.e. `javax.persistence-2.2.0.jar` is signed by the Eclipse Foundation and contains classes in the package `javax.persistence`. This jar is pulled in when some part of my application (actually something deep in Spring logic) tries to load `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory`.

If I then put a breakpoint in `java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(String, CodeSource)` on the `throw new SecurityException` line I then see that it hits this line when the passed in `CodeSource` is:

```
(file:/Users/georgehawkins/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.7.0/eclipselink-2.7.0.jar <no signer certificates>)
```

I.e. `eclipselink-2.7.0.jar` also contain classes that are in the `javax.persistence` package but it is unsigned so a clash occurs that results in a `SecurityException` being thrown. This happens when something (also deep in Spring logic) tries to load `javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil`.

If I look at the output of `mvn dependency:tree` I see that this mismatch seems to be down to `eclipselink` itself - it is pulling in `org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.2.0` itself. I.e. it isn't some clash with some other dependency:

```
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.persistence:commonj.sdo:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:compile
```

I've logged this now at bugs.eclipse.org - see bug [525457](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525457).

Comment: Additional workaround can be to switch dependency to 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:2.7.1'. It does not bring javax.persistence with it.

Comment: What Sergey said doesn't just seem like a workaround to me, but the actual solution. They responded with the same to the filed bug 525457.

Comment: I tried the exclusion approach and it didn't work; to be clear, the solution given by Sergey, which has worked for me (thanks, BTW) involved not just changing the version but also the artifactId (from javax.persistence to org.eclipse.persistence.jpa).

Answer (score 20):

To fix this issue, put in the correct JPA 2.2 compliant dependency for EclipseLink 2.7.x, in your maven pom file, as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: it took me a while to realize this is indeed the answer. I am only using the JPA support, and I do not need the "eclipselink" artifact.

Answer (score 3):

eclipselink.jar as such is designed as all-in-one bundle, not osgi enabled jar containing all partsof eclipselink project (ie sdo, oracle db specific stuff, dbws, nosql..) with ability to run with jpa api 2.0 on the classpath - at least in 2.x versions. In many cases this is not needed and proper components can be used instead, such as org.eclipse.persistence.jpa, org.eclipse.persistence.oracle etc. For the full list see ie: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.eclipse.persistence

Answer (score 3):

This strange situation still seems to exist, in my case not using Maven, just trying to get a simple JPA example to run (and it is really frustrating if you need hours just to achieve that).

With 2.7.4 from January, this error occurs if you put the eclipselink.jar and jakarta.persistence_2.2.2.jar from the zip on the classpath.

In the end solution was to change order on the classpath: first the jakarta-persistence and only after that the eclipselink-jar.
So all javax.persistence classes are taken from jakarta-jar and not partly of the eclipselink-jar (if included there).

So I really wonder various things.

The eclipselink package should be all-in-one? But it is not. Some javax.persistence classes are contained. Others not - basic classes to be used in JPA code like EntityManager. Of course, together with the jakarta-jar included in the zip it is complete - but you may not use the two jars together with the "wrong" order on the classpath!? I really consider this a bug - or at least there should be a HUGE hint about this in the package then.

What is the org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.7.4.jar from Maven that is suggested here? It does not have the problems of the eclipselink.jar yes, not this error message. But then it also just seems not to include the Eclipselink JPA implementation, at least running with it I got error that persistence-unit referenced in code does not exist (same persistence.xml working with eclipselink.jar).

Strange situation.

Answer (score 2):

My project was working on JDK-8, but stopped to work when I upgraded it to openJDK-11.
I solved it excluding the `jpa-persistence` module, and adding again on the version `2.2`:

```
   dependencies.create('org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.7.4') {
      exclude module: "javax.persistence"
   },
   'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2', //add it again, manually
   'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:2.7.4',
   'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:2.7.4',
   'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:2.7.4',
   'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:2.7.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by switching the order in which the jars appear in the classpath. In my case, I'm using Tomcat and had to modify catalina.properties to put javax before eclipselink.

Answer (score 1):

Obinna's answer is correct; I guess that there was an issue with eclipselink 2.7.x –as George indicated. I had a similar issue when upgrading eclipselink, but it was just wrong artefacts. The initially described issue seems to be a result of externally referencing javax.persistence level - it is definitely not necessary.

Proper maven configuration can be found in eclipselink wiki:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven

Answer (score 0):

I also run into this problem, with my case being a bit different, in that I am not using Maven. However, I place an answer here, as it might give people an idea about how to deal with this in their own situation. After all, the title is about this mismatch, in general, one sub-case being when using Maven.

I am using eclipselink in a NetBeans project. Initially, I was placing both the the eclipselink jar file (`eclipselink-2.7.0.jar`) and the needed org.eclipse.persistence jar files as external libraries to my project.  Comments by [Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870753/eclipselink-2-7-0-and-jpa-api-2-2-0-signature-mismatch#comment83249727_46526221) and [entreprenr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870753/eclipselink-2-7-0-and-jpa-api-2-2-0-signature-mismatch#comment85498724_46526221) above are what actually lead me to solve my problem. What I had to do was create a new library (Tools->Libraries->New Library...) which does **not** contain the eclipselink jar file (i.e. `eclipselink-2.7.0.jar` is not added in the library), only the specific org.eclipse.persistence jar files that are necessary for the project, e.g. `org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.7.0.jar`, `org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.7.0.jar`, `org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.7.0.jar`, `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor-2.7.0.jar`, `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.7.0.jar`, etc. I then added this library to my project and the exception vanished.

Of course, I also had to replace all org.eclipse.persistence jar files on my server with their 2.7.0 version and also replace the `javax.persistence.jar` with its 2.2.0 version (I use payara, so these are located under `<payara_home>\glassfish\modules`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gradle in my project build and to solve the OP's problem, which I had as well, I finally used the following working setup.

```
dependencies {

    testImplementation(group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'eclipselink', version: '2.7.4') {
        exclude group: 'javax.validation', module: 'validation-api'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', module: 'javax.persistence'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', module: 'commonj.sdo'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', module: 'jakarta.persistence'
    }

    testImplementation(group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa', version: '2.7.4') {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', module: 'jakarta.persistence'
    }

}
```

Instead of "testImplementation" you can of course use any dependency type you want or need.

After reading Sergey's comment I've improved this by just using:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa', version: '2.7.4'
}
```

I think the last one is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because I could not find an answer for this problem when only using a Tomcat and this thread is often linked with this problem, I am going to post my solution here:

Since the signature is in the MANIFEST.MF you can change the signatures in the .jar files using 7zip or WinRAR to open them or simply delete them from the META-INF files of both .jar's and then import the changed files to your IDE.

A useful thread for the Signature-Mismatch-Problem is this thread: [Java SecurityException: signer information does not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877262/java-securityexception-signer-information-does-not-match?answertab=votes#tab-top)