# Eclipselink class "javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When I try to create an EntityManager, I get this exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Perhaps it is something with the javax.persistence packages but I don't know how can I fix it.

```
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if(emf == null) {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AccountsManager");
    }
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

Here  is the persistence.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence version="2.1" 
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="AccountsManager" transaction- 
                                  type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>model.Account</class>
    <class>model.AllSubscription</class>
    <class>model.Client</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

I found similar questions but I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870753/eclipselink-2-7-0-and-jpa-api-2-2-0-signature-mismatch

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know how to exclude javax.persistence in this case.

Comment: What's your runtime and how do you build the project?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli It is an ordinary JPA project with eclipselink libraries included in the build path. And when it gets to   emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AccountsManager"); it throws the exception.

Comment: and what JAR files do you have in the classpath

Comment: My external JAR files are eclipselink.jar, jakarta.persistence_2.2.2.jar and the mysql connector.

Comment: what version is EclipseLink? And do you run it in a application server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194873/discussion-between-dexxrey-and-simon-martinelli).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I have read all possible similar topics I figured it out.

In the current version of eclipselink(2.7.4) if you add jakarta.persistence_2.2.2.jar alongside with eclipselink.jar this problem occurs. Both jars have some classes and packages with the same name. In order to fix that you have to add jakarta.persistence_2.2.2.jar before the eclipselink.jar. So all the classes are taken from the jakarta not partly.

I don't fully understand how these two libraries interact with each other, but replacing the order in the build path helped.

Comment: In addition to that eclipselink 3.0 javax.persistance does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace **jakarta.persistence_2.2.2.jar** for **jakarta.persistence-2.2.3.jar** from  [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/jakarta.persistence/2.2.3).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).